# minimum value of an multi value OrderedDict

Tags: python, ordereddict

I have an OrderedDict that each key has more than one value.

```
 <key, value1, value2, value3>
 <  1,   50  ,  1000,   20   >
 <  3,   40  ,  2000,   2  >
 <  5,   30  ,  10000,  70   >
..
```

How can I get the key of the item that has the minimum value3?
for this example, the minimum value3 would be 2. So, I want to have:

```
      <  3,   40  ,  2000,   2  >
```

or the key which is 3

Comment: Are the values a list or another dictionary?

Comment: Please provide an actual example of what you are working with, not this weird table you've created.

Comment: If you stay with this data structure, the only way to do that is to iterate through the whole dictionary and find the minimum value3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the values of the ordered dictionary are a tuple or list, you can use:

```
d = {1: (50, 1000, 20), 3: (40, 2000, 2), 5: (30, 10000, 70)}
min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1][-1])
```

Comment: May I ask why you are using `d.items` instead of `d.values` ?

Comment: Using `.items` returns the key along with the value, which the poster wanted.

Comment: Actually the OP said they wanted just the key of the item with the minimum "value3" which would be `min(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2])[0]`.

Comment: @martineau: I was going based on the example output they provided.

Answer (score 1):

Using min with a lambda function as a key.

```
m = min(d, key=lambda x:d[x][2])
```